# Global symbol "$ground" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

The following code gives the error: Global symbol "$ground" requires explicit package name at main.pl line 19.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ground=();

sub map_gen{
    my $width=10;
    my $height=10;

    foreach my $x(0..$width){
        foreach my $y(0..$height){
            push@{$ground[$x]},"-";
        }
    }
}

&map_gen;
foreach my $y(0..scalar@{$ground}){
    foreach my $x(0..scalar@{$ground[$y]}){
        print $ground[$x][$y];
    }
    print"\n";
}
```

I have researched this error and it is due to referencing an undeclared variable, but I declared @ground before the error appears. I suspect it's because its a scalar reference, but dont know how to correct it.

Comment: side note; prefer `map_gen();` over `&map_gen;`  => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912049/difference-between-function-and-function-in-perl

Comment: @mpapec: Put hyperlinks into comments using `[text](http://...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `@ground`, but you use `$ground` in the following line:

```
foreach my $y(0..scalar@{$ground}){
```

The solution isn't to declare `$ground` (as it would never have a value), but to use the correct variable

```
foreach my $y(0..scalar@ground){
```

But that loops once too many. You want

```
foreach my $y(0..$#ground){
```

Comment: Now it says syntax error at main.pl line 20, near "$#ground[" and syntax error at main.pl line 24 near "}"
here is the code: 
'foreach my $y(0..$#ground){
  foreach my $x(0..$#ground[$y]){
    print $ground[$x][$y];
  }
}'

Comment: That's not the code that's giving the error. Apparently, you used `$#ground[` somewhere. (Note the trailing `[`.) Probably trying to fix the off-by-one error on the next line. You should be using `$#{$ground[$y]}`