# Combining 2 referenced arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, pass-by-reference

Hi I have have function which returns a reference to an array like so:

```
sub get_values{
.
.
.
return(\@array)
}
```

I copy this into another array :

```
@my_val = &get_values(...);
```

The Dumper output of this is something like:

```
$VAR1 = [ '1','2',...]
```

Now I need to combine 2 of these, but when I do

```
@combined = (@my_val,@my_val_2);
```

I get

```
$VAR1 = [ '1','2',...]
$VAR2 = [ '11','22',...]
```

I need it to combine in one element like:

```
$VAR1 = [ '1','2',...,'11','22',...]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It makes far more sense to pass arrays and hashes to Dumper by ref. `print(Dumper(\@a))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is returning a reference, be prepared to take it as reference, either by dereferencing returning value,

```
my @my_val = @{ get_values(...) };
..
my @combined = (@my_val, @my_val_2);
```

or by storing reference into plain scalar,

```
my $aref = get_values(...);
..
my @combined = (@$aref, @$aref2);
```

Comment: Also get rid of `&` when calling functions if you don't have strong reason to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8915304/223226

Answer (score 1):

You are storing an array reference to an array and you don't dereference the array. The fix will be to store it to a scalar and dereference them.

```
$my_val = get_values(...);

$my_val_2 = get_values(...);

@combined = (@$my_val, @$my_val_2);
```

A custom example would be

```
$my_val = [1,2,3];

my $my_val_2 = [4,5,6];

my @combined = (@$my_val, @$my_val_2); # dereference the array and they get flattened automatically

print "@combined"; # 1 2 3 4 5 6
```