# Perl parsing config file with regex to key, value

Tags: regex, perl

I have come up with the following, to first read the file and then put it into *hash*. `=` sign used as a delimiter.

```
sub get_config_value_by_key {
    my ( $module, $key ) = @_;

    my $config = &read_file_contents(
        $config_directory . '/' . $module . '/config' );
    my %config = $config =~ /(.*)=(.*)/g;

    return $config{$key};    
}
```

It works fine, except that, if I have equal sign in the value (which I use as delimiter), then it doesn't parse it correctly.

How to fix my regex to make it work properly, escaping `=` signs in the value?

Example of config lines:

`key_1=Some value 
key_2=Some value with = sign which breaks it.`

Comment: Don't use & when calling functions... it's so unneeded! Then, unless you have to solve this for homework or golfing, I'd look into split instead of solving it all with a single regexp.

Comment: @polettix No, not the home work, I do this for my _Authentic Theme_ (for Webmin). Webmin uses `&` in front of functions a lot. I'm not Perl expert yet. Why is `&` used for?

Comment: `Re: &` please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912049/difference-between-function-and-function-in-perl

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks, pal! Will read carefully.

Comment: Summary is though: Only do it if you have a specific reason to. And even then, consider not doing so anyway, because it's probably less clear.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non greedy quantifier,

```
my %config = $config =~ /(.*?)=(.*)/g;
                          # ^_________ match smallest possible amount of chars
```

Comment: I'd also not bother slurping config into an intermediate variable. This works just as well with `<$fh> =~ m/([^=]+)=(.*)/g;` (slightly different LHS, but that's a matter of taste)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just assumed that was what `read_file_contents($filename);` was doing.

Comment: I'll check in a bit. Thanks, guys!

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks, pal! However I don't understand why. What this `?` really does?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev it makes a regex lazy (stop matching at first `=` occurrence) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/223226

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
while(<$in>){
    my($key, $val) = split(/=/, $_, 2);  
    $data{$key} = $val; 
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

This will read in a file - here `in.txt`, [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) each line on `=` into a maximum of two parts, and then assign them to a hash key/value pair.

However your approach could be tweaked to allow [non-greedy matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) `(.*?)`:

```
while(<$in>){   
    my ($key, $val) = $_ =~ /(.*?)=(.*)/;
    $data{$key} = $val;
    }
```

Comment: `split(/=/,` will split on second or third `=` sign in the line, right? I would like to see how my regex could be fixed.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - this should preserve the value string, as it only splits into two parts, and will stop after encountering the first `=`