# What is the scope of Perl's $| (OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) setting?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script running on an old CentOS 5.6 server which has Perl 5.8.8 installed. Unfortunately I can't upgrade either the OS or the version of Perl that's running on this server.

When I'm running this script from the command prompt, despite there being a `$| = 1;` statement at the top of the script (in the global scope), it still seems to buffer output to the console (over a ssh session).

Writes to both a log file and `STDOUT` are carried out by a function, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1;

&writelog("Started...");

# Do work with lots of writelog'ing

&writelog("...Done.");

exit(0);

sub writelog {

    # This is greatly simplified for the purpose of this question

    my ($logentry) = @_;
    my $logfile = "/var/log/thelog.log";
    my $logline = "$logentry\n";
    print $logline;
    open (LOGFILE, ">>$logfile");
    print LOGFILE, "$logline";
    close (LOGFILE);
}
```

Does the value of `$|` only affect output in the current scope, i.e. in this case the script's global scope? Or should it, in the example above, also cause immediate flushing to `STDOUT`/`LOGFILE` by the `print` statements in `writelog`?

Comment: I don't see why `print $logline;` would be buffered with `$|` set, the good answers notwithstanding. Perhaps `ssh` is to blame?  Btw, that `&` in front of function calls [doesn't seem needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915304/4653379).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [`perlvar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlvar.pod#$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH), `$|` has global scope and it applies only to the *currently selected output channel*. This is `STDOUT` at the beginning of any program, but can be changed with the 1-arg `select` call.

```
$| = 1;            # set autoflush on STDOUT
open LOGFILE, '>log';
my $fh = select LOGFILE;   # change "selected output channel"
$| = 1;            # set autoflush on LOGFILE
select $fh;        # restore STDOUT as "selected output channel"
$| = 0;            # turnoff autoflush on STDOUT
```

Answer (score 8):

`$|` affects only the currently selected default output filehandle.

You can explicitly set it for a filehandle like:

```
LOGFILE->autoflush(1);
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles

Answer (score 7):

[`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c) isn't a pragma; changing `$|` changes a flag in the currently [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html)ed file handle in a "permanent" fashion. By default, that handle is STDOUT.

You can affect other file handles by using

```
use IO::Handle qw( );  # Only required on older versions of Perl.
$handle->autoflush(1);
```

This is a shortcut for

```
my $temp = select($handle); $| = 1; select($temp);
```

except it tries to handle exceptions.

Comment: Trivia: `print $foo;` isn't short for `print STDOUT $foo;`; it's short for `print { select() } $foo;`.

Comment: Btw, what `{ local $| = 1; }` does to the handle, and how to check whether handle is already set to autoflush?

Comment: @Сухой2, Turns autoflush on for the selected handle, then immediately restores the old setting. This will have the effect of flushing the handle. This is abstracted by `$handle->flush`. /// You can read `$|` to obtain the current setting for the currently selected handle.

Answer (score 0):

If what you do is not working, you should look somewhere else.

If you redirect ssh to a file, it will not use a pseudo-terminal.

So you may want to use "ssh -t" to force the use of a pseudo-terminal.

You can also use the unbuffered write in perl :

```
syswrite(STDOUT, "Hello\n");
syswrite(LOGFILE, $logline);
```

Note that it is not a good idea to mix buffered and unbuffered writes on the same file handle.