# Is it possible to use hash, array, scalar with the same name in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm converting perl script to python.
I haven't used perl language before so many things in perl confused me.
For example, below, opt was declared as a scalar first but declared again as a hash. `%opt = ();` 
Is it possible to declare a scalar and a hash with the same name in perl?

As I know, `foreach $opt (@opts)` means that scalar opt gets values of array opts one by one. 
opt is an array at this time??? 
In addition, what does `$opt{$opt}` mean?
opt outside **$opt**{$opt} is a hash and opt inside $opt{**$opt**} is a scalar?
I'm so confused, please help me ...

```
sub ParseOptions
{
    local (@optval) = @_;
    local ($opt, @opts, %valFollows, @newargs);

    while (@optval) {
        $opt = shift(@optval);
        push(@opts,$opt);
        $valFollows{$opt} = shift(@optval);
    }

    @optArgs = ();
    %opt = ();

    arg: while (defined($arg = shift(@ARGV))) {
        foreach $opt (@opts) {
            if ($arg eq $opt) {
                push(@optArgs, $arg);
                if ($valFollows{$opt}) {
                    if (@ARGV == 0) {
                        &Usage();
                    }
                    $opt{$opt} = shift(@ARGV);
                    push(@optArgs, $opt{$opt});
                } else {
                    $opt{$opt} = 1;
                }
                next arg;
            }
        }
        push(@newargs,$arg);
    }

    @ARGV = @newargs;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Perl [types](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) `SCALAR`, `ARRAY`, and `HASH` are distinguished by the leading sigil in the variable name, `$`, `@`, and `%` respectively, but otherwise they may bear the same name.  So `$var` and `@var` and `%var` are, other than belonging to the same `*var` [typeglob](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), completely distinct variables.

A key for a hash must be a scalar, let's call it `$key`.  A value in a hash must also be a scalar, and the one corresponding to `$key` in the hash `%h` is `$h{$key}`, the leading `$` indicating that this is now a scalar.  Much like an element of an array is a scalar, thus `$ary[$index]`.

In `foreach $var (@ary)` the scalar `$var` does not really "get values" of array elements but rather [aliases](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) them. So if you change it in the loop you change the element of the array.

(Note, you have the array `@opts`, not `@opt`.)

---

A few comments on the code, in the light of common practices in modern Perl

- One must always have `use warnings;` on top. The other one that is a must is `use strict`, as it enforces declaration of variables with `my` (or `our`), promoting all kinds of good behavior.  This restricts the scope of [lexical (`my`) variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) to the nearest block enclosing the declaration
- A declaration may be done inside loops as well, allowing `while (my $var = EXPR) {}` and `foreach my $var (LIST) {}`, and then `$var` is scoped to the loop's block (and is also usable in the rest of the condition)
- The [`local`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()) is a different beast altogether, and in this code those should be `my` instead
- Loop [labels](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements) like `arg:` are commonly typed in block capitals
- The `&` in front of a function name has rather particular meanings<sup>†</sup> and is rarely needed.  It is almost certainly not needed in this code
- Assignment of empty list like `my @optArgs = ()` when the variable is declared (with `my`) is unneeded and has no effect (with a global `@name` it may be needed to clear it from higher scope)
- In this code there is no need to introduce variables first since they are global and thus created the first time they are used, much like in Python – *Unless they are used outside of this sub*, in which case they may need to be cleared. That's the thing with globals, they radiate throughout all code

Except for the last two these are unrelated to your Python translation task, for this script.

---

<sup>†</sup> It suppresses [prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes); informs interpreter (at runtime) that it's a subroutine and not a "*bareword*", if it hasn't been already defined (can do that with `()` after the name); ensures that the user-defined sub is called, if there is a builtin of the same name; passes the caller's `@_` (when without parens, `&name`); in [goto &name](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) and [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) ...

See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915304/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348945/4653379)

Answer (score -3):

First, to make it clear, in perl, as in shell, you could surround variable names in curly brackets {} :
`${bimbo}` and `$bimbo` are the same scalar variable.

`@bimbo` is an array pointer ;
`%bimbo` is a hash pointer ;
`$bimbo` is a scalar (unique value).

To address an array or hash value, you will have to use the '$' :
`$bimbo{'index'}` is the 'index' value of hash `%bimbo`.
If $i contains an int, such as 1 for instance,
`$bimbo[$i]` is the second value of the array `@bimbo`.

So, as you can see, @ or % ALWAYS refers to the whole array, as `$bimbo{}` or `$bimbo[]` refers to any value of the hash or array.

`${bimbo[4]}` refers to the 5th value of the array `@bimbo` ; `%{bimbo{'index'}}` refers to the 'index' value of array `%bimbo`.

Yes, all those structures could have the same name. This is one of the obvious syntax of perl.

And, euhm… always think in perl as a C++ edulcored syntax, it is simplified, but it is C.

Comment: `@bimbo` and `%bimbo` are, respectively, an array and a hash, not pointers of any kind. `\@bimbo` and `\%bimbo` are array and hash references (technically not pointers, but basically the same thing for most day-to-day uses), either of which could be assigned to `$bimbo_ref`.

Comment: You are true, in perl sense. But if you evaluate objectively the code under, it is considered as a pointer, not a whole object