# Perl array loop

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, process, status

I have an array in which I want to check if the element in the following check returns a certain value, remove it from the array if matches condition. Continue looping trough array, until all elements are gone.

```perl
foreach $temp (@inputs);
    {
        my $check = &checkStatus($temp, $server);
        if ($check ne "Z");
        print "$temp failed!\n";
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Use `grep`.

Comment: I added a piece of code, its not a working code but something along the lines I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you had a way to wait for the status of any of the items to change.

For example, if you were dealing with processes, you could use.

```
my %children = map { $_ => 1 } @pids;

while (%children) {
   my $pid = wait();
   my $status = $?;

   delete($children{$pid});

   if    ( $status & 0x7F ) { warn("Child $pid killed by signal ".( $status & 0x7F )."\n"); }
   elsif ( $status >> 8   ) { warn("Child $pid exited with error ".( $status >> 8 )."\n"); }
   else                     { print("Child $pid exited successfully\n"); }
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to poll.

```
use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );  # Time::HiRes::sleep supports fractional durations.

my %foos = map { $_ => 1 } @foo_ids;

while (%foos) {
   for my $foo_id (keys(%foos)) {
      if (checkStatus($foo_id, $server) eq 'Z') {
         delete($foos{$foo_id});
         # ...?
      }
   }

   sleep(0.1);  # To avoid using 100% CPU.
}
```

Note that in both cases, you can use the value of the hash elements to contain information about the thing.

```
 # When creating the foos.
 $foos{$foo_id} = $foo;
```

```
 # When waiting the foos.
 my $foo = delete($foos{$foo_id});
```

Comment: checkStatus will be used to check the progress of a process, it could take hours for "Z" to return, do I need a sleep command in this example?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have replaced my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), as suggested by @Shawn:

```
@inputs_wo_z = grep { checkStatus($_, $server) ne "Z" } @inputs;
```

Here, `grep` evaluates the last expression supplied to it, which is whether `checkStatus(...)` returns non-Z. By default, each element of the `@inputs` array is assigned to `$_` inside. `grep` returns all elements of the array for which the condition is true.

Note that it is not necessary to use `&` before the method call here, because you are using parenthesis. See [`perlsub`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for details, and also explained by @ikegami [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915304/967621).

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, the description of the problem is not very clear.

Your code does not delete anything from array. I assume that you want to iterate through array and only print data when element meets some condition.

Please see the following example where I imitate in an array storing temperature reported by farm of servers

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CS
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $max_temp = 36;      # maximum permited termperature

my @data = <DATA>;      # fill array with some data

for (@data) {
    next if /^\s*$/;        # skip empty lines

    chomp;
    my($s,$t) = split ',';

    say chr(0x267F) . " $s temp=$t" if $t > $max_temp;
}


__DATA__
server1,32
server2,30
server3,42
server4,32
server5,37
server6,36
server7,30
```

Output

```
♿ server3 temp=42
♿ server5 temp=37
```