# Can I call a Perl OO function without first saving the object to a variable?

Tags: perl, oop, function, methods, handle

How can I turn this two statement snippet into a single statement?

```
my $handle = &get_handle('parameter');
$handle->do_stuff;
```

Something like `{&get_handle('parameter')}->do_stuff;`, but what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: In general, you should not prefix function invocations with `&`. In your example, it would have been nicer to do `my $handle = get_handle('parameter')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
get_handle('parameter')->do_stuff
```

Related: [When should I use the & to call a Perl subroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine)

Answer (score 11):

There's no requirement for a variable to be used on the left-hand side of the `->`. It can be any expression, so you can simply use

```
get_handle('parameter')->do_stuff
```

It's actually quite common. For example,

```
$self->log->warn("foo");          # "log" returns the Log object.
$self->response->redirect($url);  # "response" returns a Response object.
$self->config->{setting};         # "config"s return a hash.
```

Comment: +1 Note, this will only work if the method returns an object.  In the example, if `get_handle('parameter')` only acts on the object but returns `undef` or something other than the object, calling `->do_stuff` will result in a run time error.

Comment: That's why we should use null objects in place of undef as return values if we want this sort of interface. ;)

Comment: @Joel, If `get_handle` returned `undef`, his original would not have worked either.

Comment: @ikegami, It just so happened that my `get_handle` would `die` sooner than return `undef`. :)