# Perl. Access caller arguments (like shift, pop, etc)

Tags: perl

In perl there is the `shift` function that can act on the `@_`(arguments of a function in scope of which it was called) if no arguments supplied.

Can I write a custom function in perl with the same behavior(some kind of my_shift)?

I tried this:

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub get_caller_args (;$) {
  my $n = shift;
  $n = defined $n? $n:1;
  my $ret;
  package DB {
    my($t,$t1) = caller($n);
  };
  $ret = \@DB::args;
  return $ret;
}

sub test ($@) {
  my $self = shift;
  print "Self: $self.\n";
  print Dumper(get_caller_args()), "\n";
}
```

It kind of works, but

```
test(1,2,3)
```

outputs:

```
Self: 1.
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
```

So it doesn't see changes made by `shift` (though it can see changes made by `pop`).

But I want it to act like this:

```
sub test {
  my $self = shift;
  print my_function;
}
```

Here the `my_function` called without arguments must act on the `@_`, in this case on the rest of the arguments, without the first as it was shifted(actually I need only to read arguments, not to do changes).

Comment: @martinclayton I tested it with perl v5.18.2, and it works for me). The problem is to write a function that can access the calling function arguments, like shift does(however I do not need to change the arguments, only to read). Is it possible? (it is not a very practical problem, of course)

Comment: Not without a call checker or other comparable messing with internals.

Comment: I'd be wondering what you're trying to accomplish. This isn't necessarily a good solution to most problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine

Comment: @ikegami: Nonsense. This is exactly what the `&subroutine` call does.

Comment: @Borordin, `subroutine(@_)`, `subroutine(\@_)` and `&subroutine` don't cause calls to `subroutine` to default to using `@_`; it's being explicit about it. If you want to default to be `@_` (like `shift`), you need a call checker or some other comparable use of the Perl API or internals.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found an answer:

```
use feature 'say';

sub my_shift {
 say "Arguments before shift: ", @_;
 shift;
 say "Arguments after shift: ", @_;
}

sub test {
 say "Arguments before my_shift: ", @_;
 &my_shift;
 say "Arguments after my_shift: ", @_;
}
```

The 'tricky' thing here is to call the `my_shift` with an ampersand(`&`) before the function name -- then the function gets arguments of the calling function as it's input.

However I'll not accept this self-answer, because I'm still interested if it possible to do this without that ampersand magic and what if i need to pass other arguments and access the calling function arguments at the same time, etc.