# Perl subroutine arguments like a hash

Tags: perl, parameters, arguments

How can I create a subroutine that can parse arguments like this:

```
&mySub(arg1 => 'value1', arg2 => 'value2' ...);

sub mySub() {
    # what do I need to do here to parse these arguments?
    # no arguments are required
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call functions using the `&mySub` syntax; just use `mySub`. See [When should I use the & to call a Perl subroutine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine)

Comment: FYI (and for future googlers, since this seems like a good canonical question), what you're describing are often called "named parameters" or "named arguments."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: that question addresses when you should use `&` and when you absolutely should not.  It and its answers do not support a broad "You shouldn't call functions using &" edict.

Comment: @ysth Perhaps I should have prefaced my comment with "in general." The vast majority of people who post here using the `&` syntax think it's required for all function calls and have no idea what the implications are, so I think saying "don't do that" and including a link to a more nuanced explanation is sufficient.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply assign the input array to a hash:

```
sub my_sub {
    my %args = @_;
    # Work with the %args hash, e.g.
    print "arg1: ", $args{arg1};
}
```

If you want to provide default values, you can use:

```
sub my_sub {
    my %args = ( 'arg1' => 'default arg1',
                 'arg2' => 'default arg2',
                 @_ );
    # Work with the (possibly default) values in %args
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll also find very useful the [`Method::Signatures`](http://search.cpan.org/~barefoot/Method-Signatures-20141021/lib/Method/Signatures.pm) module, which will allow you to do something like that:

```
func MySub (Str :$arg1 = 'default arg1', Str :$arg2 = 'default arg2') {
    print "arg1: ", $arg1};
}
```