# How can I use Text::ParseWords::parse_line when the line contains an extra unescaped double quote?

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm using `parse_line` from [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) to parse a line of text. However, when there is an unescaped double quote (`"`) inside a pair of double quotes, `parse_line` fails.

For example:

```
use Text::ParseWords; 
...
my $line = q(1000,"test","Hello"StackOverFlow");
...
@arr = &parse_line(",",1,$line);
```

I don't want to escape the inner double quote (e.g. `"Hello \"StackOverFlow"`).

Is there any other way to parse the line?

Comment: If you have csv data, perhaps `Text::CSV` might allow loose quotes with some option.

Comment: @TLP Bingo. [`allow_loose_quotes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#allow_loose_quotes) plus set `escape_char` to something other than `"`.

Comment: Side-note unrelated to your problem: you shouldn't use `&` when you call subroutines unless you know what it does and have a good reason for it. See [When should I use the & to call a Perl subroutine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine)

Answer (score 0):

Using @TLP and @ThisSuitIsBlackNot notes:

```
use 5.022;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
my $line = q(1000,"test","Hello"StackOverFlow");

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( {allow_loose_quotes => 1, escape_char => '%'});
$csv->parse($line);
my @fields = $csv->fields();
print Dumper \@fields;


__DATA__
$VAR1 = [
          '1000',
          'test',
          'Hello"StackOverFlow'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. But I need to use the parse_line function. is there any way the parse the " between the " " into \".  Just like "Hello"StackOverFlow"  ====> "Hello\"StackOverFlow"